# Unable to find valid certification path to requested target even imported cert

Tags: java, ssl

I know there are a lot of "unable to find valid certification path to requested target" topic in SOF already, but my problem is that the error is still occur even after I updated my cacert in my java folder.

To ensure that I have imported the cert, the cmd showed this to me.

```
"Certificate was added to keystore"
```

Not just like that, I still do not believe what is cmd showing me, then I used keytool -list -keystore "certpath" -alias myKey

Then the result is expected which is

```
"myKey, Sep 29, 2016, trustedCertEntry, Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): and random code going here
```

This is the error message that I get from Netbeans.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at com.novell.soa.ws.impl.transport.http.Http.post(Http.java:438)
at com.novell.soa.ws.impl.transport.http.HttpEndPoint.invoke(HttpEndPoint.java:195)
at com.novell.soa.ws.impl.soap.MessageHandlerInvoker.invokeClientMessageHandlers(MessageHandlerInvoker.java:106)
at com.novell.soa.ws.impl.soap.SOAPHandler.invoke(SOAPHandler.java:244)
at com.novell.soa.ws.impl.rpc.ClientDelegateImpl.invoke(ClientDelegateImpl.java:194)
at com.novell.soa.ws.portable.Stub._invoke(Stub.java:614)
at com.novell.soa.af.impl.soap.ProvisioningBinding_Stub.getAllProcesses(ProvisioningBinding_Stub.java:58)
at com.asia.xynapse.gateway.xpass.maxis.MobileGatewayWS.RequestQuery(MobileGatewayWS.java:337)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

and more.....

I really wish to solve it guys. I have no idea what is happening as I have already imported what I have searched online.

Comment: How many java versions installed in your machine ? Is imported java keystore and netbeans java keystore are same?

Comment: hi @Karthik i have install two version which is jdk1.7.0_79 and jdk1.8.0_101. I have imported to jre/lib/security/cacerts. I dont know about netbeans.

Comment: @Karthik There is no  such thing as a Netbeans KeyStore.